# how to print just coefficients of lm?

Tags: r, summary

If I have one row of data,`y`, like this:

```
 1 4 5 6 3 4
```

I can use the following code to find a fitted smooth curve :

```
y <- scan(text = '1 4 5 6 3 4 ')
x <- seq_along(y)
fit <- lm(y ~ poly(x,5))

summary(fit)   
newy <- predict(fit, data.frame(x))

plot(y, type = "b")
lines(x, newy, col = "red")
```

I need to do the same for 600 rows and use `summary(fit)` to get the coefficients. My problem is that I have to use these coefficients in other software and I just need the coefficients, not extra information. Is there any way to print out just the coefficients?

Comment: `coef(fit)` would be better to use than `summary(fit)`

Comment: What format do you need to transfer the information?

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks it is much better, still I  get head of it is there any way to remove it as well?

Comment: @JimO. excel should be good

Comment: @user9272398 `coef(fit)` is much better for just the raw coefficients, so much so that I deleted my original comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just `coef(fit)`. The `coef()` method should work for most statistical models in R: `model$coefficients` works for `lm` objects, but is not generally reliable. `coef(summary(model))` or `summary(model)$coefficients` give a full coefficient *table*.  (The default method for `coef()`, `stats:::coef.default()`, uses `$coefficients` to extract these values from the objects, but other model objects may work differently.)

Comment: is there any way to get just coefficients not the head?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not the head".  Perhaps you want `unname(coef(model))` ??  If you want to print the coefficients without the position indicators (like `[1]`), try `cat(unname(coef(model)),"\n")`

Comment: And to address the question of how to get the coefficients for all 600 rows, assuming your dataframe is `df`, `f <- function(row) {
     x <- seq_along(row)
     fit <- lm(row ~ poly(x,5))
     unname(coef(fit))  
     }

     coefficients <- apply(df, 1, f)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you just want the numbers without any descriptors attached. Here it is:

```
y <- scan(text = '1 4 5 6 3 4 ')
x <- seq_along(y)
fit <- lm(y ~ poly(x,5))

z <- coef(fit)
names(z) <- NULL
z

[1]  3.833333  1.553797 -2.836833  1.341641  1.133893  1.133893
```

Just remember that the first item is the y-intercept.